# R) Summary dimension table for nested lists from 'Large vtcrs_list_of'

Tags: r, nested, tibble

The data I have is large nested data set, and I apply nrow() to each nested list.

```
map(.x=df, .f=dim)

[[1]]
[1]  9 13

[[2]]
[1]  9 13

...(omit)

[[1999]]
[1]  1 13

[[2000]]
[1]  1 13

df %>% lapply(., nrow)
[[1]]
[1] 9

[[2]]
[1] 9
...

[[1999]]
[1] 1

[[2000]]
[1] 1
```

Then, how can I create a table that summarizes the number of rows from each list in Large vtcrs_list_of?
like

```
nested nrow
list1    9
list2    9
...
list1999 1
list2000 1
```

Comment: Try `df %>% sapply(., nrow)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
listname <- paste("list", 1:2000, sep = "")
nrows <- df %>% sapply(., nrow) 
final_df <- data.frame(listname, nrows)
```